# Default Text Property for Custom Button in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I've created a custom FireMonkey control, `TMyButton`, inheriting from `TControl` in Delphi. How can I make it so that when I drop a new `TMyButton` onto a form, its `Text` property automatically sets to "**MyButton1**", incrementing for each new instance ("**MyButton2**", "**MyButton3**", etc.) at design-time?

Here's a snippet of TMyButton:

```
type
  TMyButton = class(TControl)
  private
    FText: string;
  published
    property Text: string read FText write FText;
end;
```

I'm looking for a way to automate unique Text values similar to default naming in the IDE. Any advice?

Comment: In VCL, you can use `csSetCaption`. See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/Vcl.Controls.TControlStyle

Comment: You need to adjust the name when component name changes which happens in `SetName` method. So you need to override that method. There you need to detect whether component has owner (if it is nil, then it is created at runtime) and whether it is in loading state (if it is loading) then you don't want to mess with text property. Depending on those conditions you will then change your text property to the passed  parameter.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar you was right, this is how it's work in Tbutton : 

procedure TPresentedTextControl.SetName(const Value: TComponentName);
var
  ChangeText: Boolean;
begin
  ChangeText := not (csLoading in ComponentState) and (Name = Text) and
    ((Owner = nil) or not (csLoading in TComponent(Owner).ComponentState));
  inherited SetName(Value);
  if ChangeText then
    Text := Value;
end;

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You claim that you can check to see if component has owner set to nil in order to determine if it was created at runtime. But if you pass owner to component constructor then owner won't be nil even thou the component was created at runtime.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I can see that the sentence is ambiguous. My focus was not about definite detection whether component is created at runtime or not, but merely listing some things that may have impact on determining where and what to look for when writing the test property change logic.